# How can I find the number of times a set of ranges exists in a dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like some help/direction to find out how many times a set of ranges appears in an array of min/max values.

```
import numpy as np; import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000, 2),
                  columns=["Min", "Max"]) \
    .mul(6).query("Min <= Max").reset_index(drop=True)

lb = np.arange(1, 5, 0.1)
ub = np.arange(1, 5, 0.1)    

a = df[['Min','Max']].to_numpy()

factor = 1

arry = []
```

My first attempt would be to convert the min/max into a numpy array and iterate over all the arrays to produce the output.

```
factor = 1

arry = []

for row in a:    
    for x in lb:
        for y in ub:
            lbExists = 0
            rangeExists = 0
            if y <= x:
                continue
            if x >= row[0] and x <= row[1]:
                lbExists = 1            
            if x >= row[0] and y <= row[1]:
                rangeExists = 1
            project = 0
            if lbExists == 1 and rangeExists == 0:
                project -= factor
            if lbExists == 1 and rangeExists == 1:
                project = (y - x) * factor

            arry.append([round(x, 2), round(y, 2), row[0], row[1], lbExists, rangeExists , round(project,2)])
```

Output (truncated):

```
[[1.0, 1.1, 1.34, 5.8, 0, 0, 0],
 [1.0, 1.2, 1.34, 5.8, 0, 0, 0],
 [1.0, 1.3, 1.34, 5.8, 0, 0, 0],
 [1.0, 1.4, 1.34, 5.8, 0, 0, 0],
 [1.0, 1.5, 1.34, 5.8, 0, 0, 0],
 [1.0, 1.6, 1.34, 5.8, 0, 0, 0],
 [1.0, 1.7, 1.34, 5.8, 0, 0, 0],
 [1.0, 1.8, 1.34, 5.8, 0, 0, 0],
 [1.0, 1.9, 1.34, 5.8, 0, 0, 0],
 [1.0, 2.0, 1.34, 5.8, 0, 0, 0],
...
```

Then, I would like to do some analysis to find how many times each range appears in the set.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I do not see how the min/max table is transformed into the second table.

Comment: @jared I added an example, hope that clarifies?

Comment: Why not share the naive method that converts the min/max table to the other table? In other words, please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I’m not really asking for debugging my code, more how to solve the problem with numpy or pandas as the loop seems inelegant.

Comment: I know, but when it comes to vectorizing and improving code, it's helpful to see the looping code. Especially so I can run that code to get the correct output for comparison.

Comment: Your logic, input and output are unclear. Please provide a complete and reproducible input (no `...` and as reproducible code), make sure the output matches the input, and explain clearly what are the columns in the output.

Comment: Thanks all for your input, have had another attempt at the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much faster method of computation is using various `numpy` methods.

```py
# array of all valid permutations of x and y
arr_xy = np.array(np.meshgrid(lb.round(2), ub.round(2))).T.reshape(-1, 2)
arr_xy = arr_xy[arr_xy[:, 0] < arr_xy[:, 1]]

# lbExists - (x >= row[0] and x <= row[1])
lbExists = (arr_xy[:, 0][:, np.newaxis] >= a[:, 0]) * \
    (arr_xy[:, 0][:, np.newaxis] <= a[:, 1])
# rangeExists - (x >= row[0] and y <= row[1])
rangeExists = lbExists * (arr_xy[:, 1][:, np.newaxis] <= a[:, 1])

# project based off of lbExists initially (else 0)...
project = np.where(lbExists,
                   # then on value of rangeExists
                   np.where(rangeExists,
                            # (y - x) * factor if true
                            np.tile(np.diff(arr_xy) * factor, a.shape[0]),
                            # else -1 * factor
                            np.full(rangeExists.shape, -factor)),
                   0)

# combine variables
arr_out = np.hstack([
    # permutations of upper and lower bound
    np.vstack([arr_xy] * a.shape[0]),
    # repeated values of Min and Max
    np.repeat(a, arr_xy.shape[0], axis=0),
    # lbExists 2d -> 1d
    lbExists.T.reshape(-1)[:, np.newaxis],
    # rangeExists 2d -> 1d
    rangeExists.T.reshape(-1)[:, np.newaxis],
    # project 2d -> 1d
    project.T.reshape(-1)[:, np.newaxis].round(2)])
```

I have added comments throughout the code, but do ask if there is anything that needs clarifying.

The difference in timings (about x100 faster):

```py
# your loop in the question
5.84 s ± 295 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# this method
50.2 ms ± 3.49 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

And to confirm that these are the same:

```py
(arr_out==np.array(arry)).all()
#Out: True
```

Comment: Thanks @Rawson, I will give this a shot. I have update my question according to your advice, is it up to standard now?

Comment: Yes, the question is much better now.  I have rewritten my answer as the question is now quite different.