# How do I calculate a column value from inside numpy.where function

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to adjust the 'project' column calculation based on a third column in the array:

`a = df[['Min','Max','Status']].to_numpy()`

Change function to:

`(y - x) * factor * Status`

also, I would like to calculate:

`factor * (1 - x/y)`

Any hints on how to do this? My attempt below (based on Rawson's answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76647765/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-times-a-set-of-ranges-exists-in-a-dataset):

```
# array of all valid permutations of x and y
arr_xy = np.array(np.meshgrid(lb.round(2), ub.round(2))).T.reshape(-1, 2)
arr_xy = arr_xy[arr_xy[:, 0] < arr_xy[:, 1]]

# lbExists - (x >= row[0] and x <= row[1])
lbExists = (arr_xy[:, 0][:, np.newaxis] >= a[:, 0]) * \
    (arr_xy[:, 0][:, np.newaxis] <= a[:, 1])
# rangeExists - (x >= row[0] and y <= row[1])
rangeExists = lbExists * (arr_xy[:, 1][:, np.newaxis] <= a[:, 1])
# Status
statusTrue = 1 == a[:,2]

# project based off of lbExists initially (else 0)...
project = np.where(lbExists,
                   # then on value of rangeExists
                   np.where(rangeExists,
                            np.where(statusTrue,
                                # (y - x) * factor if true
                                np.tile(np.diff(arr_xy) * factor, a.shape[0]),
                                # else -1 * factor
                                np.full(rangeExists.shape, -factor)
                            ),                           
                        ),
                   0)

# And another calculated column
otherCalc = np.where(lbExists,
                   # then on value of rangeExists
                   np.where(rangeExists,
                            # factor * (1 - x/y) if true
                            # not sure how to divide the x and y value
                            np.tile(factor * (1 - np.divide(arr_xy[],arr_xy[])), a.shape[0]),
                            # else -1 * factor
                            np.full(rangeExists.shape, -factor)),
                   0)

# combine variables
arr_out = np.hstack([
    # permutations of upper and lower bound
    np.vstack([arr_xy] * a.shape[0]),
    # repeated values of Min and Max
    np.repeat(a, arr_xy.shape[0], axis=0),
    # lbExists 2d -> 1d
    lbExists.T.reshape(-1)[:, np.newaxis],
    # rangeExists 2d -> 1d
    rangeExists.T.reshape(-1)[:, np.newaxis],
    # project 2d -> 1d
    project.T.reshape(-1)[:, np.newaxis].round(2)
    # other calc 
    otherCalc.T.reshape(-1)[:, np.newaxis].round(2)])
```